# How to add linkbutton in gridview using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using search functionality in gridview using Jquery as mentioned in this article: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-GridView-with-Paging-on-TextBox-KeyPress-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx

Search functionality is working perfectly but the problem is when i add the link button in grid view like that :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="gvCustomers_RowCommand" >
<Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="legername" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="leger_name" Text='<%# Eval("leger_name") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ledgerCode" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerId" Text='<%# Eval("ledgerCode") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="control" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCity" Text='<%# Eval("control") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="delete"  HeaderStyle-Width="150px"> 
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" ID="LinkButton1"  CommandName="DeleteRecored" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' >delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

the gridview will appear with a problem and not working good

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What error are you exactly receiving?

Comment: you add this template field  to the end right?

Comment: it's not an error its appear all the BoundField under the link that I add it but when I remove the runat="server" from linkbutton the gridview appear good but the link not working

Comment: @eskaner yes I will update my question  and but all the gridview